# Is there a more idiomatic way of achieving this?

Tags: align

I've recently decided to use LaTeX as my primary document processor, I want to know can I achieve the effect of this more idiomatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
 &\phantom{\Rightarrow} &a &= b \\
 &\Rightarrow           &b &= a \\
 &\Rightarrow           &a &= b \\
 \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[Output from Tex http://snag.gy/q3FtJ.jpg](http://snag.gy/q3FtJ.jpg)

Comment: Could you elaborate? Perhaps giving a complete LaTeX example?

Comment: done (I deleted initial comment made an answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's fine to use `alignat*`, but `\phantom{\Rightarrow}` is not necessary.

And the number 5 is overkill, 2 is OK. It means 2 groups of `rl` aligned columns.

I would typeset it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
        &&   foo &= b \\
\implies&& a+b+c &= a \\
\implies&&     a &= b \\
 \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I'd probably just use `align*` as in the first example, although that uses the fact that `a` and `b` are similar widths, as can be seen in the second where I use `bb`. If you want to force alignment of the arrows you can use `alignat` but you don't need 5 columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 a &= b \\
 \Rightarrow b &= a \\
 \Rightarrow a &= b \\
\end{align*}

\bigskip

\begin{align*}
 a &= b \\
 \Rightarrow bb &= a \\
 \Rightarrow a &= b \\
\end{align*}


\bigskip

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  & a &= b \\
 \Rightarrow& bb &= a \\
 \Rightarrow& a &= b \\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```